# crystal report got error when copy to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, crystal-reports, dataset

i got problem about reporting using crystal report

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Judul, Peminjam, Pinjam, Kembali;
        DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = data.getKoneksi();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand Perintah = new SqlCommand();
        Perintah.Connection = con;
        Perintah.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Peminjaman.Katalog, Peminjaman.Pinjam, Peminjaman.Kembali, Pengguna.Nama, Buku.Judul, Buku.Jumlah, Temp.Kembali AS HrsKbl FROM Peminjaman INNER JOIN Buku INNER JOIN Temp ON Buku.ID = Temp.ID ON Peminjaman.Katalog = Buku.ID AND Peminjaman.Katalog = Temp.ID INNER JOIN Pengguna ON Peminjaman.Peminjam = Pengguna.NIS WHERE Peminjaman.Status = 'dipinjam' ORDER BY Kembali ASC";
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Adapter.SelectCommand = Perintah;
        Adapter.Fill(dtReturn);
        LapBulanan.LaporanBulananDataTable dt = new LapBulanan.LaporanBulananDataTable();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtReturn.Rows)
        {
            Judul = dr["Judul"].ToString();
            Peminjam = dr["Nama"].ToString();
            Pinjam = dr["Pinjam"].ToString();
            Kembali = dr["Kembali"].ToString();
        }

        DataTable dtTemp = dt;
        ReportDocument rpt = new Laporan();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Laporan.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(dtTemp);
        rpt.SetDataSource(dt.CopyToDataTable());
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
        rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "Laporan");
        con.Close();
    }
```

my dataset name is LapBulanan.xsd and contain datatable name LaporanBulanan(Judul, Peminjam, Pinjam, Kembali)

when i debug this program i got an error message "The source contains no DataRows" but when i check this query i got the correct record

when i remove "rpt.SetDataSource(dt.CopyToDataTable());" this crystal report is running well but i got no record on my report

thanks for your kindness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `dtReturn` datatable which has the result of the SQL query is never being used. Instead the `dtTemp` datatable that you are using contains no data because you just assign to it an empty instance of the `dt` datatable.

The foreach loop does nothing at all because it just assigns values to 4 variables that change in every iteration and never being used after that.

You don't need to set the datasource of the report twice.

So I think the code should look something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = data.getKoneksi();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand Perintah = new SqlCommand();
        Perintah.Connection = con;
        Perintah.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Peminjaman.Katalog, Peminjaman.Pinjam, Peminjaman.Kembali, Pengguna.Nama, Buku.Judul, Buku.Jumlah, Temp.Kembali AS HrsKbl FROM Peminjaman INNER JOIN Buku INNER JOIN Temp ON Buku.ID = Temp.ID ON Peminjaman.Katalog = Buku.ID AND Peminjaman.Katalog = Temp.ID INNER JOIN Pengguna ON Peminjaman.Peminjam = Pengguna.NIS WHERE Peminjaman.Status = 'dipinjam' ORDER BY Kembali ASC";
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Adapter.SelectCommand = Perintah;
        Adapter.Fill(dtReturn);

        ReportDocument rpt = new Laporan();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Laporan.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(dtReturn);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
        rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "Laporan");
        con.Close();
    }
```